# Android UIThread Dispatch Queue

Tags: android, ui-thread

I have a small question regarding how the UI Thread [works](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

> For instance, when the user touches a button on the screen, your app's UI thread dispatches the touch event to the widget, which in turn sets its pressed state and posts an invalidate request to the event queue. The UI thread dequeues the request and notifies the widget that it should redraw itself.

So what I understand is that the Button sets it state pressed to true, but what does it mean to post an "invalidate request to the event queue". Does this simply mean that the button is telling the UI Thread that I have set my state pressed to true. And why does the button not draw it self after setting it state pressed to true? Why does the UI Thread have to tell it to redraw itself? I don't know how acurate this is [here](http://www.rvasa.com/android/Lecture09/L09-UI-Thread-6pp.pdf), but it gives a slightly better pictorial of the UI thread event dispatch thread. Can anyone explain why the Widgets call invalidate to the Dispatch queue, and the UI thread asks the widget to redraw it self?

Answer (score 0):

When Button changes state, it obviously must be redrawn. What is less obvious, that some other controls may require redrawing too. Let's say our button is translucent, then to redraw button, one must redraw control(s) below it and then redraw button on the top.

Invalidate requests says not just "I need to redraw", but "this area on the screen needs redraw", and redrawing area on the screen may require (re)drawing other controls.

Also invalidating areas allows UI thread to combine redraws and instead of redrawing each (of possibly intersecting invalidated areas), it will combine them into one area and will perform single redraw, that increases performance and UI responsiveness as seen by user.